# Code that can access all major online calendars?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm working on a service that needs to be able to read items from users' calendars.  It needs to work whether the user is using Google Calendar, Exchange, Hotmail/Live, iCal, etc...

I want to do this (effectively):

```
calendar = Login(emailaddress, password); // Works for @hotmail.com, @gmail.com...
// For every item in the users' calendar extract the location of the meeting
for each (item in calendar)   
   location = item.Location;
```

I figure someone must have built some code that abstracts away the varied ways you login to these services and access the objects. But I haven't found anything yet. Any pointers would be appreciated. I don't really care what it's written in (Ruby, Python, C#, Java) as long as I can wrap it.

**UPDATE:** I've been able to get something working against the Google Calendar using the Google Calendar API. In the process I came across CalDAV and the fact that Google, Yahoo, and Apple support it. I'm going to focus on CalDAV for now, and then probably plumb in Hotmail/Live and Exchange later.  I really only need the calendar event times and location so this should not be too challenging.

**UPDATE 2:**  I have discovered DDay.iCal.  I'd like to use this as my top level abstraction within my app.  But I still have not found anything that will help me connect to, and interact with each of the popular mail systems. Nor have I found any code that shows how to layer DDay.ICal over CalDAV (which, theoretically, would give me Google, Yahoo, and Apple).  Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

There is a calendar REST API for Hotmail which is available in beta form as part of the [developer preview of the Live SDK](http://connect.microsoft.com/site1226/SelfNomination.aspx?ProgramID=7291&pageType=1). This is also a beta interactive SDK for the REST API which you can try out at http://beta.isdk.dev.live.com. Just try out the query "/me/calendars"

Comment: Sweet. Thanks Dare. So now all is left is Exchange. Gawd I hope I don't have do deal with MAPI....